# The purpose of resistor and capacitor in parallel in MCU reset circuit

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, circuit-design, schematics

I'm designing a device based on Prolific PL2773 and in reference PCB schematic there is an unusual reset circuit.

[image: PL2773 reset circuit]

VCC3 is 3.3V and reset input (RESETB) is active low 3.3V TTL input with Schmitt-trigger (Vt- 1.1V, Vt+ 1.6V). What is the purpose of R32 resistor? And, if I want to make a manual reset, is it ok to place a button in parallel with capacitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is the purpose of R32 resistor?*

R32 does two different things: -

1. It discharges the capacitor should the main power (VCC3) be removed
2. It elongates the time the device remains in reset when VCC3 is applied

Personally I wouldn't recommend designing it for (2) because there is a danger that it never comes out of reset should the Schmitt trigger threshold not be reached. Instead just make C7 a larger value.

> *if I want to make a manual reset, is it ok to place a button in
> parallel with capacitor?*

Yes it's OK but you need a small value resistor in series with the switch to avoid a high impulse discharge current. Maybe 10 Ω to 100 Ω.

Comment: Thanks! So, overall, you say that the reference design is a bad design and R32 should be removed? Could you please advice on better C7 value?

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad but, I am saying there isn't enough to go on to say it's good.